# ASSEMBLY DTA file attributes, size, name etc

Tags: assembly, findfirst, dta

I'm working with assembly for a school project and my assigments in few words requires to find files that match the given extension (*.txt, *.exe etc) and print out that file's size, date, file name etc. So far I've managed to successfully find files and set up the DTA. Everything is fine when it comes down to file name but I'm struggling when I have to print out size or date. I assume they're in binary right? How do I decode them from binary to a undestandable format?

```
      ;This is my DTA start----------------------------------
      DTA                   db 15h dup (0)
      fatt                  db 0  <-------------
      ftime                 db 0,0 <------------ how do I decode these????
      fdate                 db 0,0 <-------------
      fsize             db 4 dup (0) <----------- 
      fname             db 13 dup (0)
      ;DTA end-----------------------------------------
```

Thats my code but it's messy and a work in progress.

```
   .model small
   .stack 100h

   .data



   ;This DTA start----------------------------------
   DTA                  db 15h dup (0)
   fatt             db 0
   ftime                db 0,0
   fdate                db 0,0
   fsize                db 4 dup (0)
   fname                db 13 dup (0)
  ;DTA end-----------------------------------------

  extension     db 12 dup (0)
  sourceFHandle dw ?


  testas            db "C:\ATI\",0

   directory    db 64 dup (0)

  writefile     db "C:\menulis.txt",0
  writehandle   dw ?

  buffer    db 20 dup (?)
  simbolis  db ?



   .code

 START:
mov ax, @data
mov es, ax          ; es kad galetume naudot stosb funkcija: Store AL at address ES:(E)DI

mov si, 81h             ; programos paleidimo parametrai rasomi segmente es pradedant 129 (arba 81h) baitu        

call    skip_spaces

_2:

;; extension nuskaitymas
lea di, extension
call    read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute
cmp byte ptr es:[extension], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
jne _3
_3:

;; directory nusk
lea di, directory
call    read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute

push    ds
push    si

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

;nustatom DTA
mov ah,1ah
mov dx, offset DTA
int 21h

;; rasymui sukuria faila
mov dx, offset writefile    ; ikelti i dx destF - failo pavadinima
mov ah, 3ch         ; isvalo/sukuria faila - komandos kodas
xor cx,cx           ; normal - no attributes
int 21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Ch - create or truncate file.

                ;   Jei nebus isvalytas - tai perrasines senaji,
                ;   t.y. jei pries tai buves failas ilgesnis - like           
                ; CF set on error AX = error code.
; atidaro faila 
mov dx,offset writefile 
mov al,2
mov ah,3dh
int 21h 

mov writehandle,ax              





;keicia direktorija
mov ah,3bh
mov dx,offset directory
int 21h

;iesko failo    
mov ah,4eh
mov cx,0
lea dx,extension
int 21h

call write_to_file
;raso i faila duomenis
;   lea dx,fname
;   mov bx,writehandle
;   mov ah,40h
;   mov cx, 13

;int 21h

find_next:
mov ah,4fh
lea dx,extension
int 21h

call write_to_file

;uzdaryti faila 
mov ah,3eh
mov bx,writehandle
int 21h


mov ah,9h
mov dx,offset directory
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 0
int 21h



;; procedures

skip_spaces PROC near

skip_spaces_loop:
cmp byte ptr ds:[si], ' '
jne skip_spaces_end
inc si
jmp skip_spaces_loop
skip_spaces_end:
ret

skip_spaces ENDP

read_filename PROC near

push    ax
call    skip_spaces
read_filename_start:
cmp byte ptr ds:[si], 13    ; jei nera parametru
je  read_filename_end   ; tai taip, tai baigtas failo vedimas
cmp byte ptr ds:[si], ' '   ; jei tarpas
jne read_filename_next  ; tai praleisti visus tarpus, ir sokti prie kito    
read_filename_end:
mov al, 0           ; irasyti 0 gale
stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di = di + 1
pop ax
ret
read_filename_next:
lodsb               ; uzkrauna kita simboli
stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di = di + 1
jmp read_filename_start

read_filename ENDP

write_to_file PROC near

lea dx,fname
mov bx,writehandle
mov ah,40h
mov cx,13

int 21h
ret
write_to_file ENDP

end START
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forget. Looks like everybody else does, too. As I recall, the size is just a 32-bit number. You should be able to find some number to text routine that will do that. Time and date are a little weird. Let me see what I can find...

```
; es:di points to text buffer
mov ax, [date]
and ax, 1E0h ; month
shr ax, 5
call show_2_dec
mov al, '/'
stosb
mov ax, [date] ; again
and ax, 1Fh ; day
call show_2_dec
mov al, '/'
stosb
mov ax, [date] ; again
and ax, 0FE00h ; year
shr ax, 9
add ax, 50h ; Y2K problem?
call show_2_dec
mov al, 0 ; or '$' - terminator
stosb
; and print it
; new buffer in es:di?
mov ax, [time]
and ax, 0F800h ; hours
shr ax, 0Bh
call show_2_dec
mov al, ':'
stosb
mov ax, [time]
and ax, 7E0h ; minutes
shr ax, 5
call show_2_dec
mov al, ':'
stosb
mov ax, [time]
and ax, 1Fh ; seconds/2
shl ax, 1 ; seconds
call show_2_dec
; terminate and print
;
 show_2_dec:
aam
xchg al, ah
or ax, 3030h
stosb
mov al, ah
stosb
ret
```

That's from Nasm syntax (shouldn't bother you?) and not exactly how I did it, so there are probably copying errors, but with luck will get you pointed in the right direction(?)

Comment: This `add ax, 50h ; Y2K problem?` will not display a correct year! Since it is safe to assume the year will be post-2000 it's best to subtract 20 from this 7-bit year field.

Comment: Why not simplify the code `stosb` `mov al,ah` `stosb` to a single `stosw`? Also ANDING for both top fields (year and hours) is redundant since the next SHIFTING RIGHT will give the wanted zeroes.